# How to get rid of the malware which creates folders

Tags: macos, malware, virus

Recently I encountered some weird folders in the names of my files (including extension) which prevents some files being called. e.g. a file named `index.html` has been moved to a folder named `index.html`

How can I remove this malware?

**Note:** I'm using *Bitdefender 3.5* already updated, but it doesn't solve the problem.

**File info:**

```
ls -laO /Users/myName/Projects/myProj/build/ios-r/platforms/ios/www/index.html/index.html 
-rw-r--r--  1 myName  staff  - 1787 Jan 13 15:16 /Users/myName/Projects/myProj/build/ios-r/platforms/ios/www/index.html/index.html
```

Comment: Please open Terminal, enter `ls -laO `(<- That's an O like Ouagadougou and please note the space at the end) and move said file to the window. Copy the command including path and the result and add it to your question by editing it.

Comment: @klanomath I've added the command and result to question.

Comment: Did you encounter the same phenomenon outside your Cordova/Apache/(or whatever project that is) folder? I think it's just a misconfiguration!

Comment: @klanomath I'm not sure. but I don't think it's related to Cordova, because I'm pretty sure I'm using correct configs in my grunt file. any way, I'm trying to see if it's happen any where else or not